# How do I turn a column of lists into strings?

Tags: python, dataframe, tokenize

```
  Speaker ID                                         Utterances
0         S1  [alright Sue now it's like uh i dropped like C...
1         S2  [this year? this term?, ri- oh but you dropped...
2         S3  [yeah. hi, hi, yeah i already signed [S2: okay...
3         S4  [back in i was like w- what is that?, yeah and...
4         S5  [okay well i'm not here for a drop-add class [...
5         S6  [me, yeah. that's right, i have a question lik...
6         S7  [hello, hi, what was your name?, i thought i o...
```

Actually, the end goal is to create a new column where everything under the 'Utterances' column has the punctuation removed and has been tokenized. I just need to turn the list of strings into a string first, right?

P.S. I know the formatting is weird, but I don't know how to fix that and I haven't found an answer anywhere yet. If anyone could tell me how I'm supposed to include the text I'm working with so it doesn't look weird, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: `df.to_dict()` to post clean sample data here.

Comment: `df.Utterances.str.join(SEP)`, where `SEP` is the desired separator between the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea could be:

```
import pandas as pd
from string import punctuation
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'Utterances':[["me, yeah. that's right, i have a question lik"], ["hello, hi, what was your name?, i thought i o"]]})

df['Utterances'] = df['Utterances'].str.join(' ')
pattern = r'|'.join([re.escape(e) for e in punctuation])
df['Utterances'] = df['Utterances'].str.replace(pattern, '')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. Could you explain the part in parentheses after join?

Comment: Glad I could help, please consider also accepting my answer. `punctuation` contains all punctuations as a single string. `[e for e in punctuation]` loops through punctuation and creates a list, basically a compacter version of a for loop (google: list comprehension) `re.escape` is required because e.g. the dot character "." stands in regex as a wildcard for: every possible character. But we want to replace the dot itself and dont use it as a wildcard. Hope this helps. Happy coding.